# JavaScript Scroll current view's element id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Apologies if this question is already asked/answered. I have an html page (this page has JQuery library) with lots of paragraph tags. Each paragraph (p) tag is associated with an anchor tag with a name. Please note content inside these paragraphs may vary. When user scrolls through the page, how can I get the name of the anchor tag in the current view?

```
<p><a name="para1"></a> some long text </p> 
<p><a name="para2"></a> some text </p> 
<p><a name="para3"></a> some long text </p>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get on-screen visible element objects in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19498068/how-to-get-on-screen-visible-element-objects-in-jquery)

Comment: You can use `scrollIntoView` or `scroll` event here.

Comment: @alireza safian, yes it looks like a duplicate. The answer by Mohamed-Yousef is a different way of solving the problem. So I will keep this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).on('scroll',function(){
        var Wscroll = $(this).scrollTop();
        $('a[name^="para"]').each(function(){
            var ThisOffset = $(this).closest('p').offset();
            if(Wscroll > ThisOffset.top &&  Wscroll < ThisOffset.top  + $(this).closest('p').outerHeight(true)){
                $(this).closest('p').css('background','red');
                console.log($(this).attr('id')); // will return undefined if this anchor not has an Id
                // to get parent <p> id
                console.log($(this).closest('p').attr('id')); // will return the parent <p> id
            }
        });
    });
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/nk3c1dxj/4/)

Note: don't forget to include Jquery

To Explain : `$(this)` inside `.each()` select anchors with name starts with para ..  `closest('p')` to select parent `<p>` of this anchor .. so play around this to reach the thing you want

Comment: apparently what i am having is anchor tags inside paragraphs ( <p> <a name="para91"></a> some text <p>). I tried to use your answer on this but couldnt get it to a shape. Could you please shed some light on that

Comment: @JenonD finally? :) .. glad it helped .. you welcome and very good luck to you :)

Comment: yeah... I am actually working on a community project on my free time, and this html is loaded inside a windows form using cef winforms and it is working :-)

Comment: @JenonD Good Job .. community projects needs a lot of time and a lot of coding ... I hope you to finish it soon ..and if you need anything I'm here to help .. Good Luck :) ..

Answer (score 0):

If anybody interest of a out the box solution, take a look at https://www.customd.com/articles/13/checking-if-an-element-is-visible-on-screen-using-jquery as well. Works well when you mix it with the Mohamed-Yousef answer.

- Add jquery reference
- Add jquery.visible.js reference

> ```
> $(function(){
>  $(window).on('scroll',function(){
>   $('a[name^="para"]').each(function(){               
>       var visible = $(this).visible( false );
>       if(visible){
>       console.log($(this).attr('name'));
>       return false;
>           }       
>       });
>   }); 
> });
> ```